# Block jwt of a banned user in spring cloud gateway filter

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

i am creating a spring microservices project. my project is composed of eureka, spring cloud gateway and other microservices.
what i am doing is validating user jwt in spring cloud gateway, but validating the token only is not enough, i also want to check if user state is valid or not, for example I want the gateway to return to the client "UNAUTHORIZED" if his account is banned.

what i'm doing now is letting the user use his token until it is expired, but once the token is expired and the user tries to renew it, i inform him that he's banned and he can not get a new jwt.

what i want to do is block him even if his token is not expired yet, i don't want him to access endpoints once his account is suspended.
I know that I can call the user microservice in the gateway filter to obtain his state .. but I don't want to do this on every api call, because i think that's a little more expensive.

Are there solutions to manage this situation?

Comment: if JWT has claim of ID, you can use redis or internal Hashmap(if not production) to store all band ID's, with TTL of the token, if id exist in redis, then return code 401...

Comment: Hi Roie, thanks for your replay. i have already thought to an idea close to yours, but i want to be sure about something.. can i add a RestController in my gateway, and when the user is banned from the user-service, i send a request to the gateway to save the banned token in its database? this approach will always inform the gateway of recently banned tokens. but is the idea of creating a RestController in the gateway good or not?

Comment: no need, when user is band, save the ID to redis(from the relevant microservice), redis is a db and as such is shared between GW and all other micro services, when user goes over the filter chain in the SCG, check first if JWT id exist in redis, if so return 401